# How to make Whirlpool like animation in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation

I want to show images of user friend's in network as Whirlpool wheel like animation. Say For example, In center of view i have an button. if i click on this. the images of friends on network should be displayed like a animation of rotate and expand from the center of that button.

Like in BirdsEye in flex. Here is the Link  [BirdsEye RAVI'S Explorer](http://code.google.com/p/birdeye/wiki/RaVis)

Here is the expample graph [Click here](http://birdeye.googlecode.com/svn/branches/ng/examples/demo/BirdEyeExplorer.html) click on graph tab.

Please Help Me.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is quite simple you just need to put a Keyframe Animation to your images views:

```
//Create a Path Object witch descripes the movement - I didn*t had a better idea to make this whirpool path
UIBezierPath* path;

[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

for (NSInteger i=0; i<1000; i++) {

    CGFloat t = i/1000*M_2_PI;

    CGFloat x = t/M_2_PI * sin(t);
    CGFloat y = t/M_2_PI * cos(t);

    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x, y)];

}

// Apply a transform to the path to fit to your needs
[path applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(radius, radius)];
[path applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(centerx, centery)];


// Now Create the Animation
CAKeyframeAnimation * theAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
// Set the Path
theAnimation.path=path;
// Set the Duration
theAnimation.duration=5.0;

//Add the Animation to the Layer of the Image
[imageView.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"Whirlpool"];
```

If you add the animation to the image i schould move form the center postion in one circle to the positon (centerx,centery+radius)

More reeding you will find here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar things from a rotational particle system: (like [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eC3b3c2flR8&feature=player_detailpage#t=250s)). Perhaps you could use or extend a particle system manager for your task.